# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a problem with egovframework of Korea when I have deployed file war to Tomcat after I restarted Tomcat, it showed the error like below :

```
2011-12-23 09:16:01,101 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageRenderer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/egovframework/springmvc/egov-com-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
....................................................
```

I used :

```
[root@localhost bin]# java -version

java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (rhel-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Here is file WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<display-name>spring security</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mdo</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HTMLTagFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.cmm.filter.HTMLTagFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HTMLTagFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

        <!-- 0. 로그인 정책 컴포넌트용 필터 -->
        <!--
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginPolicyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.uat.uap.filter.EgovLoginPolicyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginPolicyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/uat/uia/actionLogin.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
     -->
        <!-- Restoration from HTMLTagFilter's action (certification login) -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:egovframework/spring/com/context-*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/egovframework/springmvc/egov-com-*.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- 1. Spring Security 필터 설정-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

        <!-- 2. Spring Security 로그아웃 설정을 위한 필터 설정 -->
        <filter>
        <filter-name>EgovSpringSecurityLogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.sec.security.filter.EgovSpringSecurityLogoutFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EgovSpringSecurityLogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/uat/uia/actionLogout.do</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- 2. Spring Security 로그인 설정을 위한 필터 설정 -->
        <filter>
        <filter-name>EgovSpringSecurityLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.sec.security.filter.EgovSpringSecurityLoginFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                        <description>로그인 실패시 반활 될 URL설정</description>
                        <param-name>loginURL</param-name>
                        <param-value>/uat/uia/egovLoginUsr.do</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EgovSpringSecurityLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- 3. EgovSSO 로그아웃 설정을 위한 필터 설정 -->
    <!--
    <filter>
        <filter-name>EgovSSOLogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.uat.sso.filter.EgovSSOLogoutFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                        <description>SSO Global Logout 처리후 반환되는 페이지 설정</description>
                        <param-name>returnURL</param-name>
                        <param-value>/j_spring_security_logout</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EgovSSOLogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/uat/uia/actionLogout.do</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        -->

        <!-- 3. EgovSSO 로그인 설정을 위한 필터 설정 -->
    <!--
    <filter>
        <filter-name>EgovSSOLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>egovframework.com.uat.sso.filter.EgovSSOLoginFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EgovSSOLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        -->


    <!-- AjaxTags configuration START-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.ajaxtags.servlets.SourceLoader</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>prefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/ajaxtags</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajaxtags/js/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajaxtags/img/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajaxtags/css/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>egovDevIndex.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/code404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
      <error-code>500</error-code>
      <location>/code500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Here is /WEB-INF/config/egovframework/springmvc/egov-com-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
        수정일                 수정자                          수정내용
  =========     =======    =================================================
  2011.09.07    서준식                  로그인 체크 인터셉터 추가
  2011.09.29    이기하                  에러페이지 경로수정
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="egovframework, example">
                <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
                <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
                <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
        </context:component-scan>


        <!-- For Pagination Tag -->
        <bean id="imageRenderer" class="egovframework.com.cmm.ImagePaginationRenderer"/>

        <bean id="paginationManager" class="egovframework.rte.ptl.mvc.tags.ui.pagination.DefaultPaginationManager">
                <property name="rendererType">
                        <map>
                                <entry key="image" value-ref="imageRenderer"/>
                        </map>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <!--
                - The form-based controllers within this application provide @RequestMapping
                - annotations at the type level for path mapping URLs and @RequestMapping
                - at the method level for request type mappings (e.g., GET and POST).
                - In contrast, ClinicController - which is not form-based - provides
                - @RequestMapping only at the method level for path mapping URLs.
                -
                - DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is driven by these annotations and is
                - enabled by default with Java 5+.
        -->

        <!--
                - This bean processes annotated handler methods, applying Application-specific PropertyEditors
                - for request parameter binding. It overrides the default AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.
        -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
                <property name="webBindingInitializer">
                        <bean class="egovframework.com.cmm.web.EgovBindingInitializer"/>
                </property>
                <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
                        <list>
                                <bean class="egovframework.rte.ptl.mvc.bind.CommandMapArgumentResolver"/>
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- 로그인 체크가 필요한 URL과 로그인 여부를 체크해줄 인터셉터를 등록한다. -->
        <!--
        <bean id="selectAnnotaionMapper" class="egovframework.rte.ptl.mvc.handler.SimpleUrlAnnotationHandlerMapping" p:order="1">
                <property name="interceptors">
                        <list>
                                <ref local="authenticInterceptor" />
                        </list>
                </property>
                -->
                <!-- 로그인 체크가 필요한 URL 리스트  -->
                <!--
                <property name="urls">
                        <set>
                                <value>/**/*.do</value>
                        </set>
                </property>
        </bean>
        -->

        <!-- 로그인 체크 인터셉터 -->
        <!-- <bean id="authenticInterceptor" class="egovframework.com.cmm.interceptor.AuthenticInterceptor"> -->
        <!-- 인증 체크가 필요 없는 URL 리스트  -->
        <!--
                <property name="permittedURL">
                        <set>
                                <value>/uat/uia/[a-zA-Z]+\.do</value>
                                <value>/EgovLeft.do</value>
                                <value>/uat/uia/actionLogin.do</value>
                        </set>
                </property>
        </bean>
        -->

        <!--
                - This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical
                - view names for error views. The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet
                - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: this will happen
                - here with all other types of exceptions.
        -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
                <property name="defaultErrorView" value="egovframework/com/cmm/error/egovError"/>
                <property name="exceptionMappings">
                        <props>
                                <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException">egovframework/com/cmm/error/dataAccessFailure</prop>
                                <prop key="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException">egovframework/com/cmm/error/dataAccessFailure</prop>
                                <prop key="egovframework.rte.fdl.cmmn.exception.EgovBizException">egovframework/com/cmm/error/egovBizException</prop>
                                <prop key="org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException">egovframework/com/uat/uia/EgovLoginUsr</prop>
                        </props>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <!--
                - This bean configures the 'prefix' and 'suffix' properties of
                - InternalResourceViewResolver, which resolves logical view names
                - returned by Controllers. For example, a logical view name of "vets"
                - will be mapped to "/WEB-INF/jsp/vets.jsp".
        -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:order="1"
                  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
                  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>

        <!--
                - Message source for this context, loaded from localized "messages_xx" files.
                - Could also reside in the root application context, as it is generic,
                - but is currently just used within Application's web tier.
        -->
        <!-- <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages/message-common"/> -->
</beans>
```

Comment: What Tomcat version are you using?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;

That method was added in [Servlet 2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29).

So this problem can have at least 3 causes:

1. The servlet container does not support Servlet 2.5.
2. The `web.xml` is not declared conform Servlet 2.5 or newer.
3. The webapp's runtime classpath is littered with servlet container specific JAR files of a different servlet container make/version which does not support Servlet 2.5.

To solve it,

1. Make sure that your servlet container supports at least Servlet 2.5. That are at least Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, JBoss AS 4.1, etcetera. Tomcat 5.5 for example supports at highest Servlet 2.4. If you can't upgrade Tomcat, then you'd need to downgrade Spring to a Servlet 2.4 compatible version.
2. Make sure that the root declaration of `web.xml` complies Servlet 2.5 (or newer, at least the highest whatever your target runtime supports). For an example, see also somewhere halfway [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).
3. Make sure that you don't have any servlet container specific libraries like `servlet-api.jar` or `j2ee.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` or even worse, the `JRE/lib` or `JRE/lib/ext`. They do not belong there. This is a pretty common beginner's mistake in an attempt to circumvent compilation errors in an IDE, see also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project).

Comment: Good answer, only point 2 is not correct. At least with Spring, if you don't declare Servlet 2.5 in your web.xml, but instead use 2.4 or before, there won't be Servlet 2.5-specific code executed, so you can't get the OP's error.

Comment: In my case, another dependency (Axis2) was loading servlet-api 2.3. Putting Axis2 at the end of my dependencies in pom.xml solved the problem. Tnx!

Comment: Are there any more than these 3? I am suddenly getting this message after yum auto-updated from tomcat 6.0.35 to 6.0.36. None of the webapps or jars have changed as far as the logs show...

Comment: This answer solved my issue. I had javax.servlet version 2.4 in my pom.xml and was getting issue. But, when I changed it to 2.5, my issue get resolved. Feels great :D

Comment: One of the examples:If you use CXF Web Services and put all jars from CXF package into Tomcat/lib directory, that will create a conflict because CXF contains geronimo-servlet_xxx JAR with the javax.servlet.ServletContext interface.

Comment: I had the servlet 3.0.1 declared in my pom but another dependency had a transitive one on servlet-api-2.4. I exclueded the 2.4 version and everything worked.

Comment: Why servlet-api.jar or j2ee.jar in /WEB-INF/lib is bad? Doesn't the app of java start to find jar in WEB-INF/lib firstly then the tomcat/lib?

Comment: @gfan: Because it can be of a completely different version than the server is designed for and hence end up in conflicts in all colors because API classes/methods are missing/changed. In the last link in the above answer you can find more detail on that.