# tomcat 7.0.57 startup issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to start the tomcat from the command line on windows 7, but getting a lot of errors... I tryied to find something related but couldn't find anything similiar.

First, I downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.57. 
From the command line, I set the JAVA_HOME with the path of the jdk - the version is jdk1.7.0_51.
then I used the startup command.

from catalina logs:

```
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
נוב 21, 2014 5:01:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\Users\Hadas\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\docs
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8611825/2231632

Comment: No, I've seen it already. Different errors.

Comment: Have you tried to run as administrator? Once change your tomcat directory put it to another directory and test again.

Comment: I did, still doesn't work.

Comment: I downloaded the new versions of tomcat and jdk and now it's running.