# 404 Requested resource not available when running simple Spring MVC HelloWeb

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For this I also read some older posts on stackoverflow but I do not get solution I needed.

I am creating a simple Spring MVC HelloWeb application.

For this I am using following files

1) `web.xml` for configuring DispatcherServlet

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Spring MVC Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

2) Then I am writing Simple `HelloController` as follows :

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
@Controller
public class HelloController{
@RequestMapping(value="hello" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
return "hello";
}
}
```

3) After that I configured `HelloWeb-servlet.xml` as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint"></context:component-scan>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
<property name="order" value = "1" ></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

4) `hello.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

5) package-nfo.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
```

I exported the war to the tomcat 7 webapps folder and restarted the tomcat service.

I checked HelloWeb app in the tomcat console it was running.

I hit url `http://<URL>:8080/HelloWeb/hello.`

And I got the following error

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWeb
>   threw exception
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       root cause
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
>   name'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping':
>   Initialization    of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean
>   (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:255)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:672)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:640)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:435)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:334)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:323)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:498)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:81)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:66)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:78)
>     org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:76)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:274)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:427)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:341)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) root cause
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandler(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java:108)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:80)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:69)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:70)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1331)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:255)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:672)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:640)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:435)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:334)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:323)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:498)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:81)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:66)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:78)
>     org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
>     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:76)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:274)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:427)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:341)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: The title is wrongly posted by me my issue is following error

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean

Comment: Which version of Spring you are using?

Comment: see answer offered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611777/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getcontextpathljava

Comment: Hi Gaurav, did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to mismatch in Spring jars versions. I upgraded my application to Spring 3 from Spring 2 . We need to remove spring-2.5.6.jar  as it is not required with Spring 3.It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an slash in your RequestMapping. Could you try with the next fix?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and am still getting the error

Comment: Is it the version mismatch issue for the jars in the classpath?commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,javaee-api-5.jar,org.springframework.asm.jar,org.springframework.beans.jar,org.springframework.context.jar,org.springframework.core.jar,org.springframework.web.jar,org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar,spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,spring-web.jar in my classpath

Answer (score 0):

In 'HelloWeb-servlet.xml' enable the annotation config by adding ''. You have used the annotation in controller class but how Spring container identifies the Controller.