# Spring Boot in WSO2AS

Tags: spring, wso2, wso2-as

I have a project built with Spring Boot, and let me know if you can deploy WSO2AS.

Try deploy as war but fails, any ideas?

This is error since "**WSO2AS-5.2.1**"

```
TID: [0] [AS] [2015-08-06 14:23:11,242]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-08-06 14:23:11,242+0200] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [AS] [2015-08-06 14:24:09,835] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase} -  ContainerBase.addChild: start:  {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase}
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-osb-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:280)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:222)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:174)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:147)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

A greeting.

Comment: It would be better, if you added that stacktrace rather than adding image of it.

Comment: And it traces this error.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Already deployed but I had to put another version of Spring Boot "1.1.12.RELEASE". The new error but is running the WS "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl"

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611777/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getcontextpathljava)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably spring boot version uses standard JSR356 based websocket implementation. But WSO2 AS 5.2.1 supports only the tomcat specific websocket implementation.
You can use WSO2 AS 5.3.0 Alpha pack and test the new functionality. It supports JSR356 based standard websocket implementation